# Problem pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python

Help with 'pygame.error: video system not initialized' problem

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

Black = (0,0,0)
Gray = (150,150,150)
White = (255,255,255)
Screen_width = 640
Screen_height = 480

class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(Black)

        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None,20)
        self.text_image = self.font.render(text, True, White)

        self.text_rect = self.text_image.get_rect(center = (width//2,height//2))
        self.image.blit(self.text_image,self.text_rect)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.centery = y

    def update(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.image.fill(Black)
        else:
            self.image.fill(Gray)

        self.image.blit(self.text_image, self.text.rect)

scr = pygame.display.set_mode((Screen_width, Screen_height))
scr = pygame.display.set_caption('Заголовок окошка игры )')
my_button = Button('Это моя кнопка', Screen_width /2, Screen_width /2, 100,100)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(my_button)

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if my_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                print('Кнопка нажата!')

        all_sprites.update()
        all_sprites.draw(scr)
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

In lane 'mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()' problem 'pygame.error: video system not initialized' is ruining process. I dont know what is wrong. I tried to init python and import sys to simulate video-access, but, however, nothing happen. I red a lot of articles, but i think there is something another...

Comment: You could try to put pygame.display.init() under your pygame.init()? Or maybe try and redo pip install pygame.

Comment: Already) Still don't work